# Laravel 5.1: Eloquent relationship hasmany, Limit records

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem with Laravel 5.1: Eloquent relationship hasmany, Limit records I have 2 tables: feeds, comments. The request is to obtain 5 feeds and comments accordingly to each particular feed. I am currently using the below query:

```
public function getFeed($user_id){
    return Feed::whereUserId($user_id)->with(['comments'])->take(10)->get()->map(function ($feed) {
        $feed->comments = $feed->comments->take(5);
        return $feed;
    });
}
```

However, it returns all the comments.

My thinking was that the `$feed->comments = $feed->comments->take(5);` line doesn't work. I only want to get 5 comments for each feed, do you have any advise? Any comments are highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If it's something that will apply in all cases, you can adjust the relationship in the Feed model like this:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->limit(5);
}
```

Comment: this will not work, it will limit the whole query in the case you use it in a `->with()` method. As a consequence you will only ever get 5 comments as a whole, while you actually wanted 5 comments "per" parent relation.

Answer (score 3):

It's better late than never, I was facing the same issue yesterday and ended up by sets the entire relations array on the model.

So in your case it will be like this:

```
return Feed::whereUserId($user_id)->take(10)->get()->map(function($feed) {
         $feed->setRelation('comments', $feed->comments->take(5));
         return $feed;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue for over a month now. I just wanted to optimize the query because it was taking almost 1.5 sec to load desired data from 1 million records.

I leveraged [Eloquent ORM Collection Load()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-load) method. This reduces the load time to just 300 ms.

In your case,

```
return Feed::whereUserId($user_id)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($feed) {
        $feed->load('comments')->take(5);
    })
});
```

Comment: I think the limit/take needs to be defined inside the load function parameter like this `$feed->load(['comments' => function ($query) { $query->take(5); }]);`

Comment: this results in N+1 queries issue

Answer (score 1):

```
$feed= Feed::whereUserId($userId)->with(['comments'])->get()->map(function ($query) {
            $query->setRelation('comments', $query->comments->take(10));
            return $query;
        });
```

Comment: Please add some explanations with your code so that will help the person who asked the question

Answer (score 0):

```
Feed::whereUserId($user_id)->with([
    'comments' => function($query) {
         // You should limit the comments by editing the
         // relationships query not the main query.
         $query->take(5);
    }
])->take(10)->get();
```

This way you can limit the feed count you want and the comment count each feed has.

Comment: this will limit the fid not comments

Comment: No this will limit both of them

Comment: whit will not working , this code will limit the the Feed 10
and will get only 5 comments and will share them with the 10 feed

Answer (score 0):

the `take()` eloquent method just adds 'limit' word at the end of the query. this type of query is more complex and isn't supported by vanilla eloquent.

fortunately, there is an additional package called [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit), which helps with this problem. in order to make it work, install that package by using `composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit` command and put `use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;` line inside both parent and children model classes.

Answer (score -1):

The error might be here

`$feed->comments = $feed->comments->take(5);`

Which should be

`$feed->comments = $feed->comments->take(5)->get();`

I will suggest you write in this way

`$feed->load(['comments' => function($query){ return $query->take(5); }])`

Comment: `take()` is a confusing function: it is mapped to `limit()` for query instances, and it is not related to queries when you call it on a collection instance. I suggest to only use it when you are working with a collection instance. In that case, you wont ever need to call `->get()` since that means a different thing in a collection.